# How do I get rid of this 'warning: the expression is unused' warning?

Tags: object, kotlin, compiler-warnings

Trying to figure out why I'm getting a warning in this code.

```
object Test {
  val bar = true

  operator fun invoke(foo: Test.() -> Boolean): Boolean {
    return foo()
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println(Test {bar})
}
```

You get this when you compile

> test.kt:5:12: warning: the expression is unused
>   return foo()

But it certainly seems to be used, since you do get `true` when you run it.

Comment: Are `return`s implicit in `operator` definitions?

Comment: The `return` is mandatory in this case: _"A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')"_ I can't find an explanation for the warning, though.

Comment: Just double checked, and the warning also comes up in non operator functions.  Though oddly in the non-trivial code that I extracted this example from I got the warning for `invoke` but not `get`.  In this trivial example it appears for both operators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `foo()` explicitely on `this` will make the warning go away:

**1st way:**

```
operator fun invoke(foo: Test.() -> Boolean): Boolean {
    return this.foo()
}
```

**2nd way:**

```
operator fun invoke(foo: Test.() -> Boolean): Boolean {
    return foo(this)
}
```

Since you should be able to omit `this` in this context, I would guess that it is a bug in the compiler.

---

If you just want to warning to disappear, you can use the `@Suppress` annotation at the statement level:

```
operator fun invoke(foo: Test.() -> Boolean): Boolean {
    @Suppress("UNUSED_EXPRESSION")
    return foo()
}
```

You could do it for the whole file, the whole class or the whole function as well, but it is better to use it directly at the statement because other unused expressions could really be a mistake of yours (and not by intention) and the compiler wouldn't tell you about it then.

Answer (score 4):

This false positive you've identified is a known issue in Kotlin [KT-21282](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21282), so you can either apply one of [Willi's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54337529/4951255) or wait for JetBrains to fix the bug.

Comment: i knew it's a bug! nice that you found the ticket +1 :)